# Using python venv with custom libraries

Tags: python, python-import, setuptools, python-packaging

I'm working in a Linux environment and using a *venv*. I come from *C++* and structured the whole project assuming the existence of something akin to *CMake*. Basically my idea was to keep well separated the "libraries" from their respective tests, and when the libraries are fully developed to call them inside of a main program. I built it like this:

```
mainFolder:

- .venv

- devel (containing the tests)

-- devel_modules1

-- devel_modules2

-- devel_modules3

- modules (containing the modules)

-- modules1

-- modules2

-- modules3
```

Each of `devel_modules1-3` contains several python files to test the corresponding file in `modules1-3`; I would like to be able to use an import statement "from anywhere" as long as I'm using the *venv*. My understanding is that to do this I should treat modules as a package, install it with *pip* and it should just work (???).

In each of `modules1-3`, I placed a file `__init__.py` containing

```
`__all__=[list of all the python files in this folder]`
```

In modules, I placed an empty `__init__.py` file and a file `setup.py` containing :

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
import pathlib
here = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.resolve()

setup(
    name="modules",
    version="0.0.1",
    packages=find_packages(where="src")
)
```

When I launch

```
pip3 install -e modules
```

It works without raising any error and is correctly listed in the installed packages;

But when I try to launch `someTest.py` contained in `devel_modules` I get the error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'modules'
```

from the line

```
from modules.modules1.fileModules1 import DatabaseConnector
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Typically you would never want to have `setup.py` and `__init__.py` in the same directory. I would recommend to change the directory structure. -- Will you want at some point to distribute these libraries independently from each other?

Comment: No the libraries are not independent of each other. How should I change the directory structure? Not having the libraries somewhat organised is my last choice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the project structure I would recommend:

```
modules
├── .venv
│   └── ...
├── pyproject.toml
├── src
│   └── modules
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── modules1
│       │   ├── __init__.py
│       │   ├── some_module.py
│       │   └── ...
│       └── modules2
│           ├── __init__.py
│           └── another_module.py
└── test
    ├── test_modules.py
    ├── modules1
    │   └── test_modules1.py
    └── modules2
        └── test_modules2.py
```

`pyproject.toml`

```ini
[build-system]
build-backend = 'setuptools.build_meta'
requires = [
    'setuptools',
]

[project]
name = "modules"
version = "0.0.1"
```

This is a "canonical" project structure. There should be no need for `setup.py` or `setup.cfg`. The `src`-layout is automatically recognized by *setuptools*, this layout protects from some common import issues during development phase when used in combination with the "editable" installation (`.venv/bin/python -m pip install --editable .`). The tests can be nested as much as needed, a "*test runner*" like *pytest* should be able to handle this without issues.

Comment: I like this proposed structure. But out of curiosity, how would one handle relative imports? I mean, imagine that you want to reference a function/class from a file located in modules2 from a file located in modules1? How would the import statement be writen and would it be compatible with the test modules?

Comment: I recommend against relative imports. The advantages are not worth it in my opinion. With that said, there is nothing particular about it. Use sequences of dots to climb back up the package hierarchy, two dots `..` to go one level up, three dots for two levels.

Comment: Thanks for answering! Can I also ask you 1) what was the mistake in my approach 2) Why would you avoid relative imports and how should I do it? Say that modules2 contains the data models and modules1 uses them; what's the optimal approach?

Comment: ***1)*** I am not entirely sure what was wrong in your approach, the content of the question was not clear to me, I had to make some guesses, but I could definitely spot some red flags that showed me that your overall project structure and understanding of Python packaging was shaky. Most notable was the location of `setup.py`, and the fact that using a `setup.py` is outdated. So easier for me to explain from a clean slate.

Comment: ***2)*** I recommend people to avoid relative flags, because they are a bit tricky to get right, and I had to answer too many questions about them here on StackOverflow, all for no clear advantage that I can see and feel entirely justified. My recommendation is to always use absolute imports. I wrote a bit about it [here](https://sinoroc.gitlab.io/kb/python/python_imports.html). -- With absolute imports, always start the import from the top-level package `modules`, for example: `from modules.modules1 import data_models`. Relative: `from ..modules1 import data_models`