# static resource within package are not found after wheel module installation

Tags: python, python-packaging, python-poetry, python-wheel

I have `pyproject.toml` that looks like this

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "cmd-tool"
version = "0.1.0"
description = ""
authors = []
readme = "README.md"
repository = ""
documentation = ""
packages = [
    { include = "src" }
]

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.10"
click = "^8.1.3"
pandas = "^1.5.2"
openpyxl = "^3.1.1"
jinja2 = "^3.1.2"

[tool.poetry.scripts]
execute-script = "src.cli:cli"


[tool.poetry.group.dev.dependencies]
pre-commit = "^2.20.0"
pytest = "^7.1"
pytest-cov = "^4.0.0"
hypothesis = "^6.62.0"
black = "^22.12.0"
mypy = "^0.940"

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core>=1.0.0"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"


[tool.pycln]
all = true
verbose = false

[tool.black]
line-length = 88
target-version = ["py310"]

[tool.mypy]
python_version = "3.10"
plugins = ["pydantic.mypy"]
disallow_untyped_defs = true
show_error_context = true
show_column_numbers = true
ignore_missing_imports = true
pretty = true

[tool.isort]
profile = "black"
```

And my project structure looks like

```
cmd-tool/
   src/
       __init__.py
       cli.py
       excel/
       ast/
       ....
       /static
           mapping.json
```

where `cli.py` is a basic command-line function

```
@click.command()
@click.option("--operation", "-o", "op", required=True, help='command to execute (generate-columns, generate-payload)')
@click.option("--source", "-s", "src", type=File('rb'), required=True, help='source file which will be transformed')
@click.option("--destination", "-d", "dest", required=True, help='destination file to which write the change')
def cli(op: str, src: File, dest: str):
    """Manipulates files"""

    # ugly workaround to support multiple file types
    if dest.endswith('xlsx'):
        dest_file = open(dest, 'wb')
    else:
        dest_file = open(dest, 'w')
    
    match op:
        case 'generate-columns':
            ExcelProcessingService().generate_columns(src, dest_file)
        case 'generate-payload':
            ExcelProcessingService().generate_payload(src, dest_file)

    dest_file.close() # dest parameter is required
```

When I run my script `execute-script` using `poetry run execute-script ....` it works fine. However if I build the project using `poetry build` and install created `whl` package - it fails with the error `No such file or directory: 'src/static/mapping.json'`

This error comes from this file

```
from src.ast.util import parse_args_method_signature, parse_kwargs_method_signature

# load mapping
import json
with open('src/static/mapping.json', 'r') as json_file:
    mapping = json.load(json_file)

def _render_decimal(value):
    decimal_type, left_right = parse_args_method_signature(value)
    if left_right:
        return f"{ mapping[decimal_type] }(left_digits={left_right[0]},right_digits={left_right[1]})"
    else:
        return f"{ mapping[decimal_type] }"

def _post_process_field(value):
    if not value.endswith(')'):
        value = f'{value}()'
    return value

def render_fields(value):
    if value.startswith('decimal'):
        return _post_process_field(_render_decimal(value))
    else:
        return _post_process_field(mapping.get(value))

def render_faker_expresison(attribute_name, expr):
    return [attribute_name, *parse_kwargs_method_signature(expr)]
```

That is located in `excel/column/processor.py`

Why it works when I run it as poetry run but does not work as `whl` package?

After installation of the wheel package it is certainly there (in `lib/python3.10/site-package`)

[image]

What is the problem?

Comment: The JSON file should be packaged as "*package data*". Look it up. Then reading the JSON file should be done with `importlib.resources`. This has been asked and answered many times in other questions.

Comment: but I add `src` as package in my `pyproject.toml` no? or is it different?

Comment: Well, having something called `src` as a top-level import package is another red flag for me that the packaging of this project is fundamentally incorrect. I recommend you read [this tutorial](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/) and pay close attention to the project's directory structure. Typically you want the top-level importable package of your project to be something like `my_package_name`. In your case, I guess `cmd_tool` maybe, so that one can `import cmd_tool` and so that the entry point is `cmd_tool.cli:cli`.

Comment: Why haven't you let Poetry create the initial project directory structure and used it?

Comment: we adhere to the same standard in all the projects with `/project-name/src`. it is just that not many projects use poetry in the first place (but plain python with setup and so on). so I created a basic project and adjusted it (not like I wanted to changed to `src` in the first place)

Comment: the confusing thing is that `static` folder is included in wheel package. It is not like it is exlcuded. It is just unable to access it but I guess `importlib.resources` should solve the problem.

Comment: ok, it seems `importlib.resources` helped

Comment: Then you need `project_name/src/project_name` where the second `project_name` is the top-level importable package. This is the convention in Python. You do no want to have a `src` top-level importable package, this does not make sense. No one wants to `import src` in their code, this is silly. With *Poetry* you can create the project directory structure with [*`poetry new --src project_name`*](https://python-poetry.org/docs/cli/#new). -- Here is an example I wrote the other day about a "*canonical*" project directory structure with `src`-layout: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75572982

Comment: got it. I will try to restructure it and try again.